# is there a way to call data using generics function?

Tags: swift

I have a simple struct and a data model:

```
struct Phone: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var size: String
    var model: String
    var price: Int
}

let PhoneData = [
    Phone(size: "L", model: "New", price: 500),
    Phone(size: "X", model: "Old", price: 400),
    Phone(size: "X", model: "New", price: 600),
    Phone(size: "M", model: "New", price: 650)
]
```

I want to create a generic function, that takes input, be it a size, model or price, and returns the value of it

I tried this

```
func returnWhatever<T>(whichProperty: T) -> Any {
    let phone = PhoneData[0]
    return phone.T
}
```

But it prints "Value of type 'Phone' has no member 'T' "

I dont want to have three functions for each property of the data model like this one for size:

```
func returnWhatever() -> String {
    let phone = PhoneData[0]
    return phone.size
}
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: `size` and `model` are both `String`s.

Comment: A very minor observation, but I would advise starting `PhoneData` with an upper case letter. I'd suggest `phoneData`, or, since it's not a `Data`, perhaps `phoneArray` or just `phones`.

Comment: You want a function that only return values for the first element of an array, what good would a function like that do? And why not use properties like `phoneData.first?.size`, `phoneData.first?.model` and `phoneData.first?.price`

Comment: @Rob yes you are correct, i was doing it in a rush, my mistake

Comment: @Joakim it is part of a larger project, this is a simplified example, i am just looking for the best solution, instead of using 3 functions, i want to use 1

Comment: And with my suggestion you will not be using any function but only properties. I just fail to see that the function you want adds any value but maybe I am missing something

Comment: yes, your suggestion is completely valid. however in our project we are using one more parameter and several conditions, just looking for the principle here. but thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [key-path expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID563):

```swift
struct Phone: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var size: String
    var model: String
    var price: Int
}

let phones = [
    Phone(size: "L", model: "New", price: 500),
    Phone(size: "X", model: "Old", price: 400),
    Phone(size: "X", model: "New", price: 600),
    Phone(size: "M", model: "New", price: 650)
]

func returnWhatever<T>(_ property: KeyPath<Phone, T>) -> T {
    let phone = phones[0]
    return phone[keyPath: property]
}
```

And then

```
let value = returnWhatever(\.price)
```

---

Or as [Jesse said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65250006/1271826), you can use a closure because Swift 5.2 allows key path expressions as functions ([see SE-0249](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0249-key-path-literal-function-expressions.md)). Thus:

```swift
func returnWhatever<T>(_ block: (Phone) -> T) -> T {
    let phone = phones[0]
    return block(phone)
}
```

And again this key-path expression syntax works:

```
let value = returnWhatever(\.price)
```

Comment: great! thanks for detailed description, key-path expression is a new topic to me

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense as it is. Maybe you're asking for this?

```swift
Phone.propertyOfSomePhone(\.price)
```

```swift
extension Phone {
  static let all: [Self] = [
    .init(size: "L", model: "New", price: 500),
    .init(size: "X", model: "Old", price: 400),
    .init(size: "X", model: "New", price: 600),
    .init(size: "M", model: "New", price: 650)
  ]

  static func propertyOfSomePhone<Property>(_ property: (Self) -> Property) -> Property {
    property(all[0])
  }
}
```

Comment: let me rephrase a little bit- i want the function to return a value(String, or Int) based on the input(whichProperty), which is a property of the Phone(Size, Model, Price) : so i call it returnWhatever(whichProperty: size) and it returns "L" or returnWhatever(whichProperty: price) and it returns 500. And the values are from the Phone at position 0 in the array

Comment: That's not what your question says, but it is what's in my answer.

Comment: yes, you are correct, my mistake, i am sorry, thanks for your help!